# restricting characters in a string in django

Tags: python, django

I will like to find out how do i restrict the job.description, a string to a certain number of characters? (I want to limit it to 3 rows in my .html).

template(.html)

```
{{ job.description }}
```

forms.py

```
 class Meta:
        model = Job
```

models.py

```
description = db.StringProperty(multiline=True, verbose_name='Description:')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in filter to limit a string to a certain number of characters, but you can limit to a certain number of words:

```
{{ job.description|truncatewords:20 }}
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#truncatewords

If you really want to restrict to a number of characters, you will have to write your own custom filter.